# Xamarin.Forms Firebase DB read from database

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

Currently I'm struggling with 'get' from FireBaseDB in Xamarin Forms PCL project.
I have installed FirebaseDatabase.net and Firebase.Xamarin from NuGet.
On button click I have something like this:

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://*.firebaseio.com/");
var Name = await firebase.Child("Name").OnceAsync<TestClass1>();
```

where TestClass1:

```
public class TestClass1
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I start application, on button click I get:

> Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: Exception occured while
>   processing the request.
>
> Url: https://*.firebaseio.com/Name/.json
>
> Request Data:
>
> Response:

Firebase rules are:

> {   "rules": {
>       ".read": true,
>       ".write": true   } }

Firebase Data is:

> AppName
>
> ---Name: XXX

What I should do more to read from DB. Should I add something more from NuGet or use different Packages.
Thanks for help.

EDIT:
Everything was working fine...my Android emulator didn't have Internet connection